How to Implement PageFlipWidget in SyncFusion Flutter PDF
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';
import 'package:test_ebook/page_flip/page_flip_widget.dart';

class PdfViewerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String pdfLink; // URL or network link to the PDF

  PdfViewerScreen({required this.pdfLink});

  @override
  _PdfViewerScreenState createState() => _PdfViewerScreenState();
}

class _PdfViewerScreenState extends State<PdfViewerScreen> {
  final PdfViewerController _pdfViewerController = PdfViewerController();
  final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('PDF Viewer'),
        ),
        body: Stack(children: [
          SfPdfViewer.network(
            widget.pdfLink,
            key: _pdfViewerKey,
            controller: _pdfViewerController,
            enableDoubleTapZooming: true,
            enableDocumentLinkAnnotation: false,
            pageLayoutMode: PdfPageLayoutMode.single,
            scrollDirection: PdfScrollDirection.vertical,
            onPageChanged: (PdfPageChangedDetails details) {},
          ),
        ]));
  }
}



I want to add PageFlipWidget to above code.
Any one who can help me to figure it out?
Is there any way to get pages of the pdf. so that I can build a pageFlipWidget with childrens as pages. But I also want to use the functionalities of Syncfusion PDF view such as Highlight text etc.
page flip widget package link: https://pub.dev/packages/page_flip

Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are not open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.
